# Migrate Legacy Application to Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration, dao

I have an application with a custom framework, it's very old 7 years ago using old techniques and design patterns.

We are facing problems.
We are using DAO Layer to access the Data objects and by the business need things getting so complicated and DAO is no longer being able to serve the business needs, we are thinking to use Symmfony2 and Doctrine2.

But the problem is :
THE APPLICATION IS REALLY BIG.
More than 7 years development and adding features.
About 11.500 Files and File Avg 1500 Line.

I know it's not an easy job, but i'm sure there's a way to migrate or at least use Doctrine for now without hurting the legacy code.

Please Advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to your problems. Dealing with legacy code is always hard.

You should wrap Symfony around your application if possible. Implement a Command or Facade pattern around your app, and make the Symfony controllers call those classes.

Try to separate your DAO access layers by using the repository pattern. Not the Doctrine repositories, but custom ones, specific to your app. When you have repositories separated with interfaces from your app, you can do doctrine implementations of them one by one.

It would be worth thinking about decoupling your application from Symfony so you don't face these kind of problems in the future.

Also, if you can, try to write as many tests as possible, this will make it much easier for you to refactor in the future.

I wrote a blog post with some tips on how to separate from the framework [here](http://thesolidphp.com/decoupling-application-from-framework/). The same pattern applies for repositories.